# How is a 16:9 aspect ratio Powerpoint presentation displayed on a 4:3 monitor using screen share in Zoom?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, zoom-meeting, aspect-ratio

I have a Powerpoint presentation with slides in a 16:9 aspect ratio that is going to be given at a meeting over Zoom. However, there are some concerns with how Zoom will present the presentation if there is a 4:3 aspect ratio monitor. I.e., if the presentation is in a 16:9 format but one of the meeting participants has a 4:3 monitor, will Zoom resize the presentation to fit their screen or will the edges of the presentation get cut off?

I have tried searching how Zoom and Powerpoint interact in this manner, but there seems to be no documentation of this. Most of the discussion seems to be about aspect ratios more generally. It is unclear how Zoom handles this because obviously it does have to deal with clients using monitors of different aspect ratios.

Comment: I would try first to see if anyone has a 4:3 monitor. I had one of the last ones and that was in 2008 (T61p with portrait screen)

Comment: Use a remote desktop session and resize the window to approximate 4:3 sizing.

Answer (score 2):

Zoom will size the content to fit the window. It always defaults to fit to application window as this is the simplest method that will work on all screens. It does not attempt to "intelligently" resize the content. A 16:9 content being shared will have black bars at the top and bottom on a 4:3 program window.